# How to loop through an array using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have an an array as follows:

```
var data = new Array();
if(j==1){
  data['name']=$('input:text[name=full_name]').val();
  data['email']=$('input:text[name=email]').val();
  data['password']=$('input:password[name=password]').val();
  data[' ']=$('input:password[name=retype_password]').val();
}
```

I want to loop through with this array as follows:

```
$.each(data,function(index,value){
  alert(index + ": " + value ); 

});
```

But no alert box is appeared that proves .$each() does not work. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: `$.each()` looks at the type of the object you pass it.  If it's an array, then it iterates properties from `0` to `.length - 1`.  Your array has no such properties so you get no iteration.  If you use an object instead `var data = {}`, then `.each()` will iterate all the properties on that object and you will see what you want.  You are misuing an array and should be using an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have is an object(key value pair) not an [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) where objects are stored using an index.

So you need to create `data` as an object, not as an array

```
var data = {};
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6hX79/)

Answer (score 1):

Use object instead of an array

```
var data = {};
if (j==1) {
    data['name']=$('input:text[name=full_name]').val();
    data['email']=$('input:text[name=email]').val();
    data['password']=$('input:password[name=password]').val();
    data[' ']=$('input:password[name=retype_password]').val();
}

$.each(data, function(i, v) {
    alert(i, v);
});
```

An array maps index to a value, not key to a value, i.e.:

```
var A = [];
A.push('John');
A.push('Mike');
A.push('Sally');
console.log(A[1]); // prints Mike
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
var j =1;
var data = {};

if (j == 1) {
  data['name'] = 'Rachit';
  data['email'] = 'patelrachith@gmail.com';
  data['password'] = 'rachit';
  data[' '] = 3;
}

$.each(data, function (index) {
 alert(index + " : " + data[index] );
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/patelrachith/FZy3b/1/